# How to Disable Warning for MySQL 5.6.14 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: mysql

Our MySQL error log contains several thousands of the following Warning: `Client failed to provide its character set. 'utf8' will be used as client character set.`

We're using MySQL 5.6.14 CE Server on Windows Server 2012. I can't figure out how to get the warning to go away.

I've tried updating the ODBC DSN to use a specific character set, tried setting the charset in the connection string, and tried setting numerous variables in my.ini, and restarted the database. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error Log: Client failed to provide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910279/mysql-error-log-client-failed-to-provide)

Comment: marked as duplicate only to keep one question per problem. can't help with you question, probably you should ask for [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69160) escalation. however, it wont always work since mysql acquired by oracle, as from my experience, in oracle support average resolution time even for oracle db non-critical bug exceed several moths. deterministic way of bug reconstruction helps considerably, as support tends to reply `can't reproduce` several times before getting in action (no offence, just experience from a ORCL gold partner)

Comment: There is a bug open about it, which apparently also applies to non-ssl connections. [Bug #69160 character set warning when using ssl](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69160)

Comment: I'm the one that posted that I was having the issue with non-ssl connections :)

Comment: alko, deleted other question. this one is more succinct. while i'd like to understand the problem further, I'm more interested in getting it to stop right now.

Comment: did you try to disable warnigns at all, with [`--log-warnings=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings)?

Comment: I tried adding it to the my.ini, but didn't help. Does it have to be a command line parameter?

Comment: I tried adding it as a command line parameter to my service, but then MySQL wouldn't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the connector for our websites to the latest version and this warning has stopped appearing. I'm just going to go out on a limb and guess that the 1.10.1.0 version of MySQL Connector/.Net was not passing the charset variable I had placed in our connection strings.

Still curious why `--log-warnings=0` parameter prevents the MySQL service from starting, and why `log-warnings=0` in the **my.ini** did not stop the warning from showing up in the error log, but I guess that is another question.